# Copying inbuilt perl documentation into txt file

Tags: perl

I want to copy the perl documentation which is inbuilt in perl 5.28 into a txt file. I am trying it as :

```
  my $file =  "D:/perldoc.txt";
  open(my $fh , '>',$file) or die "file not found" ;
  print  $fh "perl doc\n";

  #perldoc perldoc;                   NOT HELPING
  #$fh = perldoc perldoc;             NOT HELPING

  close $fh; 
  print "done\n";
```

The method I am trying isn't correct, Please correct me.

Comment: Why are you trying to do it from a perl script? Isn't it just `perldoc perldoc > D:\perldoc.txt` in cmd?

Comment: Yes it is! but how to do it using a script , or say you are doing some processing in perl getting a output, then how to get that into a txt file using perl?

Comment: In Perl I could run `system 'perldoc perldoc > D:\\perldoc.txt';`. If I wanted to put the result of some calculations into a file, I'd do it like your code: open the file, print to it, then close it.

Answer (score 1):

See https://perldoc.pl/perlop#qx/STRING/ for how to run a command and capture its output in Perl. But another option in this case is to use modules directly.

First [Pod::Simple::Search](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pod::Simple::Search) to find the perldoc:

```
use Pod::Simple::Search;
my $path = Pod::Simple::Search->find('perldoc'); # or the name of the module/documentation you want to read
```

Then [Pod::Simple::Text](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pod::Simple::Text) to convert it to text:

```
use Pod::Simple::Text;
my $parser = Pod::Simple::Text->new;
$parser->output_string(\my $text);
$parser->parse_file($path);
```

Finally, [File::Slurper](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurper) or [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) to write out the text after whatever modifications.

```
use File::Slurper 'write_text';
my $outfile = 'perldoc.txt';
write_text($outfile, $text);
```

-or-

```
use Path::Tiny;
my $outfile = 'perldoc.txt';
path($outfile)->spew_utf8($text);
```